# sites view is small even when I use meta viewport

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

We are building a site, and when we run it on our local servers (Our private wifi 10.0.0.whatever) it worked fine.
Now we uploaded the site online, and when opening the sites on our mobile the scale is PC scale.

We already are using the tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

We do not understand whats the problem... The site is responsive.
Any thoughts?

The site is implmented in AngularJS and using bootstrap library.

An image for reference.... from W3schools.[image]

This is the start of my head div:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="rtl" ng-app="siteNameApp" style="padding-bottom: 80px;">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>siteName</title>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you share your website link?

Comment: Please note it is not in English, it is for child education. and thanks

Comment: you use <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> in frameset, but not in parent html where you add <title>Textrategia </title> just add this meta tag blow this title.

Comment: beah its not readable, I will edit my question to show my head div

Comment: we tried that, it still the same :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though what @Ajay said was the right answer, in my case, the site view was wrong because Go-daddy domain warped our site with their own HTML Header. 
Make sure the site header is your own and not someone else's.

As Ajay said, the meta div should be in the *index header*

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```